# Incorrectly multiplying

Tags: c++

so I have a program that expresses decimals in different bases and has the potential of displaying an infinite number of decimal places because of its nature. However when I try base 2 and input in .258, it gives 01000010000011000100100110111010010111100011010101 but stops there even though I am certain that it is a repeating decimal. **It is important to note that the program does not store the number rather displays the individual digits as soon as it gets them and then promptly forgets them.** here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double a;
    double b;
    cout << "input base then input the decimal\n";
    cin >> a >> b;
    while (b) {
        b*=a;
        cout << int(b);
        b-=floor(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at the GNU MPFR library for high precision numbers: http://www.mpfr.org/.

Comment: You don't have an infinite number of bits to encode the decimal value. Hence the truncated result.

Comment: *"I am certain that it is a repeating decimal"*  You are correct that it would take an infinite number of bits to store.  Are you asking why an infinite number of bits aren't being used?

Comment: @Drew Repeating decimal need not require infinite bits to store. Consider 1/3 on a base 3 machine.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) - must read.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `b` is a double precision floating point variable. The value you store in it is the closest representable value to 0.258. This value, like all binary floating point values, has a binary expansion that terminates. After all, you are storing it in a 64 bit wide variable.

Your expectations are incorrect. Whilst the number stored in `b` may have a repeating *decimal* representation, the *binary* representation must terminate.

Comment: +1  I suspect that *repeating binary digits* was intended in the question regarding decinal .258, though.

Comment: okay, thanks. I'm still new to programming in C++ so this was helpful.
Also I find it interesting that my Ti-84 calculator can run a similar program fine to any number of decimal places.

Comment: @user There's a huge difference between decimal places and binary places.